# Memory analysis could not be completed due to insufficient memory. Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, dump, dotmemory

I try to analyze a 35 GB dump file using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise on a 48 GB RAM virtual machine. But after a while, I got the Memory analysis could not be completed due to insufficient memory, but only 20GB of RAM was used.

I've tried to:
Tools -> Options ->Debugging -> Symbols -> Select "only specified modules" 
but without success.

When I try to open it with dotMemory it loads and utill 20GB and after that is not doing anything, but the loading screen is still present for more than 24 hours

Comment: Does dotMemory utilize CPU? What version of dotMemory do you use?

Comment: It does utilize ~28% of CPU

Comment: And what version of dotMemory do you use? :)

Comment: JetBrains dotMemory 2019.1.2, i'll try to install the latest version (2019.3.3)

Comment: Most probably dotMemory still processing the graph of objects, there should be JetBrains.Common.ExternalStorage process consuming CPU and memory, on huge graphs it could take very long time, depending on the graph topology. It will finish the process, but how much time it will take is unpredictable.

I would recommend you to get the latest version of dotMemory and try to open this memory dump file with it, we reworked how dotMemory is processing the snapshot on opening. Now it calculates only basic data and allows starting to work much earlier. All other data is calculated on demand.

Comment: Yes, there is a process JetBrains.Common.ExternalStorage consuming ~27% of CPU. I will let it process for the entire weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I let dotMemory to process the file over the weekend and it got processed indeed. The best part is that its a one-time process and after that, it will load processed data from the disc. So the solution for me was to upgrade to the latest version(because I let it process for like 24h with an older version and it didn't work) and let it process. Thanks Ed.ward for support.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved your problem. Just out of curiosity, how many objects are there in the graph?

Comment: There are ~ 18 GB of objects and ~50 000 000 objects